# Read Child nodes including text and node using XPath from XElement ? LinQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

Using old way of doing via XmlDocument,

```
string xmlstring = "<root><profile><Name>John</Name><Age>23</Age></profile></root>";
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlstring);
string childNodes = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("root/Profile").InnerXml;

// output of childNodes would be => "<Name>John</Name><Age>23</Age>";
```

what is the equivalent of doing the above execution in LinQ when you have XElement variable. I see XPathSelectElement method in XElement but it doesn't return the child nodes + Child nodes text. Any Ideas?

Comment: Why do you want to get `InnerXml`? What do you want to do with it afterwards?

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use XPath at all for this. I'd use:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
var nodes = doc.Root
               .Elements("profile")
               .DescendantsAndSelf();
```

That give the `profile` nodes and all their descendants. It's not really clear what you're trying to do with the results, but if you can give more details I should be able to come up with the appropriate code.